# Метод, который проверяет возможность хода фигуры на шахматной доске

Tags: java

Cell[] way(Cell source, Cell dest)
dest - задает ячейку, куда следует пойти. Если фигура может туда пойти, то Вернуть массив ячеек, которые должна пройти фигура.

Comment: Во-первых, у вас не введено понятие фигуры в методе. Во-вторых, это не простая задача для произвольной фигуры: ее решение не поместится в обычном ответе, даже для случая, когда все клетки, кроме занимаемой ходимой фигурой, свободны. В-третьих, не всегда по текущему состоянию на доске можно определить допустимые ходы: иногда нужно анализировать историю. В общем, предлагаю переформулировтаь вопрос.

Comment: Этот метод будет в классе Figure. Можно ли написать какой-то универсальный метод, чтобы потом наследовать класс Figure и непосредственно вызывать его под определенные условия. Условия напишутся в классе для каждой фигуры

Comment: @Dmitry Tokar, нет, нельзя (точнее можно, но это заметно сложнее), т.к. каждая фигура ходит по-своему, и, более того, в зависимости от цвета, позиции и текущей истории ходов.

Comment: Т.е. можно (и скорее нужно) оставить этот метод абстрактным, и реализовывать в каждой фигуре отдельно. А потом еще проверять доп. условия, связанные с историей.

Comment: Простите, забыл предупредить. Это задание для совсем начинающего. Все фигуры буду одного цвета, съедать друг друга не будут. Суть задания состоит в том, если ход возможен, то вернуть массив с ячейками. Если нет, то throw исключение. Без каких-либо доп условий

Comment: Абстрактным его от меня и хотят. Я пока совсем не понимаю как его реализовать даже в примитивном виде. Реализовывать в каждой фигуре я буду позже

Comment: ну так и напишите: protected abstract Cell[] way(Cell source, Cell dest) throw WayNotExistsException; А исключение наследуйте от другого исключения, например, от Exception.

Comment: С телом самого метода не поможете?

Comment: Абстра́ктный ме́тод — в объектно-ориентированном программировании, метод класса, реализация для которого отсутствует. Вы предлагаете реализовать то, что не имеет реализации.

Comment: Я просто не понял своего задания. Спасибо большое